# Switching panels in Adobe After Effects using Extendscript

Tags: extendscript, after-effects

In After Effects I have written a panel that (among other things) switches between different compositions using Extendscript.

I use the myComp.openInViewer() function to switch between compositions.

A side effect of this function is that the viewer becomes active. This means that you first have to click on my custom panel before the user can click on the next action. This is a bit of a hassle, because the point of my script is to quickly compare compositions and a few extra click defeat the whole purpose.

Is there a way to put the focus back on my panel via a Extendscript command (or something else)?

I use After Effects CC 2014 on a pc. The panel is written in html5 and thus uses a lot of embedded JavaScripts. Through these scripts I call the .jsx-files.

Hope there is a solution.

Thanks,

Geert